# What is the purpose of call stack?

Tags: javascript

I was learning JS and came across the term "call stack". I found out that it helps to keep track of invoked functions but I unfortunately cannot see the real benefit of that, that is, what problems call stack help us to solve and what actual benefits it brings to us during development. For these two questions I cannot find answers thus decided to ask in the platform.

Comment: The call stack is used in almost all languages, not just JS. When you call a function, it remembers what function to go back to when it returns.

Comment: It has nothing to do with development, it's just the way computers keep track of what they're doing.

Comment: @wewq Refer [Understanding the JavaScript call stack](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-the-javascript-call-stack-861e41ae61d4/) for good explanation.

Comment: It’s not like Wikipedia didn’t have a full article on it either …

Comment: @Barmar Of course It has to do something with development, because the way computers keep track of what they are doing, has been developed by a programmer. Computers do not do anything on their own.

Comment: @ceving I never think about the call stack while I'm programming, any more than I think about registers. They're just part of the internal operation of the computer.

Comment: @ceving "I was learning JS"...

Comment: @Barmar This means that you have never written an interpreter. But may other have developed one. And doing so is development, in particular demanding development.

Comment: @ceving Of course language implementors have to deal with it, I'm talking about language users.

Comment: Call stack just keep tracks of the thread of execution of the program, for detail overview have a look https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 1):

The memory of a process is divided in two parts the *stack* and the *heap*. When you allocate memory explicitly with `malloc`, the heap is used. When you allocate memory implicitly by calling a function the stack is used. The function parameters and local variables are pushed onto the stack. When the control flow leaves the function the variables are removed from the stack. When a function calls another function, the variables of the second function are pushed on top of the variables of the first function. This leads to a very long stack of variables, called the call stack. Every function call pushes new variables on the stack.

This is a famous paper about the stack: ["Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit"](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs161/fa08/papers/stack_smashing.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack)

> A call stack is a mechanism for an interpreter (like the JavaScript
>   interpreter in a web browser) to keep track of its place in a script
>   that calls multiple functions — what function is currently being run
>   and what functions are called from within that function, etc.

For example, we can see what call stack has while executing recursion function on each iteration:

```
function pow(x, n) {
  return (n == 1) ? x : (x * pow(x, n - 1));
}

pow(2, 4)
```

The maximal recursion depth is limited by JavaScript engine. Usually, 100000 is probably out of limit for the majority of them. So we can throw the error, if we call `pow(2, 10000)`:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

Another example:

```js
const sum = (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
}

const mult = (a, b) => {
    return a * b;
}

const dividing = (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
}

const subtraction = (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
}

sum(1, 2);
mult(1, 2);
dividing(4, 2);
subtraction(4, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

A [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is what a program uses to keep track of where it is. Imagine you have the following code:

```js
firstMethod();

function firstMethod() {
  secondMethod();
  thirdMethod();
}

function secondMethod() {
  // I do nothing
}

function thirdMethod() {
  fourthMethod();
}

function fourthMethod() {
  // I also do nothing
}
```

A pseudo call stack will behave something like this (keep in mind that this is greatly simplified, and only an abstract representation to show you how it works):

> 1. firstMethod();

`firstMethod` will call `secondMethod`, so the call stack (when `secondMethod` has been called) looks like this:

> 1. firstMethod()
> 2. secondMethod()

Then, `secondMethod` has finished execution, and the program goes back up the call stack:

> 1. firstMethod()

`firstMethod` calls another function now, `thirdMethod`. After this call, the call stack will look like this:

> 1. firstMethod()
> 2. thirdMethod()

`thirdMethod` will call `fourthMethod`, so the program does not go back up to `firstMethod`, but will add `fourthMethod` to the call stack:

> 1. firstMethod()
> 2. thirdMethod()
> 3. fourthMethod()

After `fourthMethod` has completed execution, the program will go back up the call stack and complete execution of all methods that it encounters:

> 1. firstMethod()
> 2. thirdMethod()

`thirdMethod` also finished execution, the program goes back up the call stack:

> 1. firstMethod()

When all code in the first entry of the call stack has been executed, the program finishes execution.